# VS 2019 .net core 2.2 error - error occurred determine the process id of dotnet.exe

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have been looking all over and I cannot seem to fix this error.

> visual studio 2019 throws error 'An error occurred attempting to
> determine the process id of dotnet.exe which is hosting your
> application. An error occurred while sending the requests

I'm trying to debug an application, but I cannot run this locally.  I keep getting this error:
[image]

Everything I search says there is an issue with the SSL on my machine.  I checked, I did have this under my Personal / Certificate.  I fixed this and now have localhost under Trusted Root Certification Authorties.  I am still getting this error.

Another post I found said to add the following to environment variables.
Key:    DOTNET_HOST_PATH
value:  dotnet

This project is a .NET Core 2.2 web application, I am running visual studios pro v 16.8.3.  I did recently install .net 5.0, I wasn't sure if this was causing the issues so I uninstalled .net 5.0.  I am still having the issue after uninstalling it.

Comment: fyi .net core 2.2 is out of support

Comment: Yeah, that I know.  This is an existing application I'm trying to fix a bug.  Not worth upgrading, it's kind of a house of cards

Comment: Are you running from IIS Express? If so, try to kill all `iisexpress` processes berfore running again. Also, you might want to double check you application for startup errors. Try run with `dotnet run` and see if there's any relevant exceptions being thrown there. If there's a startup error that makes you application exit before debugger can attach to it, you get this error too.

Comment: You can input `cmd` in your windows search to open your `Command Prompt`,then input `setx DOTNET_HOST_PATH "%ProgramFiles%\dotnet\dotnet.exe"`,then close VS and restart.

Comment: @tgarcia, it is running on IIS Express.  I uninstalled it and re-installed.  Still get the error. There were no other errors than this popping up.

Comment: @Yinqiu, I have tried with just adding dotnet and with a direct path to the exe, still get that error.

Comment: On another note, I copied the code directly to another computer and I did not get this error.  The only difference between the two is my work computer is running VS version 16.8.3 compared to my personal computer which is running 16.8.2

Comment: @AndyH that's odd. Given this works in another machine, I'd give this a try: clean up `/bin` and `/obj` folders, then rebuild and run. If it doesn't fix, I would create another empty project with dotnet2.2, make sure it runs, then compare the generated launchSettings.json with the one you already have to look for any clues.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if there's a permission issue with my computer's image.  Most of my co-workers are able to run this.  There is another co-worker who has the same issue as me and we had our computers imaged at the same time.  But, I'm going to try and create new project and see if I can get that to run.

Comment: I went ahead and uninstalled and tried to reinstall visual studios.  I'm still having the same issue.  Everything I read says it's a cert issue on my computer. Originally I had a localhost cert under Personal / Certificates.  I read things that said to delete that and move to trusted root certification authorities, I did that and it didn't help.  So now I reverted so it's back under personal and removed the one from trusted root, no difference.

Comment: @tgarcia, you asked what the output was. I don't see any errors, but I do see this

The thread 0x0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program 'JavaScript debug adapter: about:blank' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[11664] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Hi ,have you solved this issue?copy my code to your computer is not helpful?

Comment: @AndyH I really was kind of hoping that you could see something in `stdout`. So, the original message was just reacting to the fact that dotnet application exited before iisexpress could attach to it. Today I had a similar error (no quite the same) after mistakenlly targeting a .netcore3.1/netstandard2.0 package to .net5.

Comment: @AndyH Also, I was looking through some histories here, and found a very similar issue I came across some time ago. I fixed it by removing some Sonarqube-related configuration in `.csproj` and `web.config` and a few unused `.res` files. Some machines could run normally then, but others would run only via `dotnet run` command. In that case, I am still not quite sure what was causing the error, but I suspect that it was some Visual Studio extension's fault.

Comment: @Yinqiu, no this hasn't been fixed yet.  I did try your suggestion and it didn't work as well.  Still looking into this.  Thanks!

Comment: One of the biggest frustrations is, trying to look up this error, all information comes back from 3 or more years ago.  Seems like there isn't much on this for 2019 VS

Comment: @bhargavrao Please vote to undelete this answer, I have deleted the duplicate from the other post.